# Rails 3: Route design for displaying filtered list

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have two resources: `comments` and `communities`, and each comment is associated with one or more communities.

My plan is to have the URL `/comments` display all comments, and `/comments/:community_name` display only those comments from the given community. The URLs should route to the `comments#index' action to retrieve the set of comments from the Comment model (using a [named scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303772/rails-3-correct-syntax-for-named-scope-with-method-call-and-model-associations)).

How can I generate these routes? (Or if there is a more appropriate route design, please let me know.)

If I try nested routes below, it seems I am required to supply a comment id i.e., `\comment\:comment_id\communities\:community_id`.

```
#routes.rb
resources :comments, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
resources :communities, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
resources :comments do
  resources :communities
end
```

Note: The communities resource must be an independent resource as I require actions to view, add, and remove communities.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the following line of code in `#routes.rb` and check it:
`match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'`

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :comments, only: [:index, :create, :destroy] do
  collection do
    resources :communities, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

This routes declaration will give you URLs like:

```
comments/communities
comments/community/1, etc
```

If you want to use community-name as a community id, and you will want to do that for most of your resources, then it's better to use a nice gem like [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) for your resources.